Is comparing the AIC of a Bayesian and a frequentist model right?
I’m trying to fit a general linear model where the dependant variable is a probability. It is zero-inflated and continuous, then following the advice here blog of Ben Bolker, I separated my data pool and choose to make two different regressions, one being without the null values.
For more context, I modeled landscape connectivity of a region with graph theory. I then tried to  assess the importance of nodes in the overall network with a metric named dPC_Flux. This metric is calculated at the scale of a node, and can be interpretated as “The increase of probability that two individuals can reach each other through the ecological network, given the presence of this node” . This metric is my dependant variable. The independent variable are local environmental properties of the node.
I have some issues deciding which family I should use in my glm. I’ve tried first transforming my dependant variable and my independent variables to have paired linear relationships, and then fitting with a gamma family with glmmTMB.
Model1=glmmTMB(dPC_Flux ~ Distance_2nd_plus_proche_voisin + 
                        Corridor_max +
                        Petites_infra_transport +
                        type_esp:Prairie + 
                        Compaction_infra_transport + 
                        type_esp:Foret +
                        Habitat_hors_tache +
                        type_esp:Sfc_eau + 
                        Routes1 +
                        type_esp:Espace_ouvert,
                      data = data,
                      family = Gamma(link = "log"))

I have also tried fitting a beta regression without any transformation, but faced with difficulties to converge, I used a Bayesian approach with stan_betareg.
Beta_Flux_gare= stan_betareg(dPC_Flux ~ Distance_2nd_plus_proche_voisin + 
                             Corridor_max +
                             Petites_infra_transport +
                             type_esp:Prairie + 
                             Compaction_infra_transport + 
                             type_esp:Foret +
                             Habitat_hors_tache +
                             type_esp:Sfc_eau + 
                             Routes1 +
                             type_esp:Espace_ouvert,
                           data = data, 
                           link= "logit",
                           cores=5)

Both models are computed with R.
My question is : How can I decide which one is the best ? Can I compare the AICs of both models ? Do I need to compare the AIC of the frequentist model and the BIC of the bayesian one ? Or am I missing something and the reasoning itself is incorrect ?
Thank you in advance

Welcome to CV.   AIc and BIC aren't comparable.  I've never heard of comparing a bayesian and frequentist model to decide which is "better"   there are ways to do betareg in R, and probably code for your other models in Stan. Good luck!

Could you be more precise on which models you like to compare?

Thanks a lot for your replies. I added some precision about the models i wanted to compare. I will try to compute the betareg correctly without the bayesian approach (or the gamma regression with Stan). I will try to decide wether to choose one approach upon the other.

Generally speaking, you cannot compare models across the Bayes/Frequentist divide. But a way to bend the rules would be to recast one of the models in the other paradigm: for instance, Bayesian models with informative priors often have a direct equivalent in the form of a regularized likelihood function. Similarly, most frequentist models are to some extent Bayesian models with flat priors.
